# Construction a sequence of real numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can we construct a sequence $\{a_{i}\}$, where $0<a_{i}\leq 1$ for all $i$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=\frac{B_{n}}{2^{n}}$  such that $B_{n}\to b$ as $n\to \infty$ for some $1\leq b <\infty$?

**Edit**: What about $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=\frac{n}{n+1}$, or $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=B_{n}$ with $B_{n}\to b$, could we find such $a_{i}$?

Comment: Edited twice while I was trying to read it = most annoying. If $B_n\to b$ then the right side goes to zero, but the left side doesn't.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, my bad! So what about $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=\frac{n}{n+1}$, or $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=B_{n}$ with $B_{n}\to b$, could we find such $a_{i}$?

Comment: About the Edit: try $a_n=B_n-B_{n-1}$.

Comment: ?? What is your question, in the end? Given $(B_n)$, find $(a_n)$, or, given $(a_n)$, find $(B_n)$, or find $(B_n)$ with $B_n\to b$ for some given $b$, or what?

Comment: @did: yes, this is working, by taking $a_{i}=\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether $(B_n)$ converges or not does not really matter. That such a sequence exists is equivalent to $$0<\underbrace{\frac{B_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{B_n}{2^n}}_{\text{ this would be }a_{n+1}}\leq 1,$$ for $n\geq 1$, since this uniquely determines the sequence $(a_n)$ as above with $a_1=B_1/2$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the good reply!

Comment: What happened to the condition $B_n\to b$?

Comment: @did: That is something one can check independently.

Comment: Michael: My question was directed at Ben more than at you, nevertheless: if $(B_n/2^n)_n$ is increasing and $B_1=2a_1\gt0$, I wonder how $(B_n)$ can possibly converge to a finite limit.

Comment: @did: You are right, the only nonnegative sequence for which this works is constant zero. It should work for some nonpositive sequences though.